# Database Design for hierarchical Data

Tags: database, database-design

I am trying to design a database to store large amount of urls. Now i want to have count of different combinations among parts of url. for example how many time mens section comes with flipkart? how many time flipkart has come? any idea how to design it effeciently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a structure similar to the one posted by @rjhdby. But apart from that, you'll need some programmatic consolidation of URL paths for the so-called 'sections'. Some are not really useful depending on the site. So you need a mapping which you can grow/build and then periodically filter on to determine which parts of URLs you consider useful. That could happen automatically since common parts will repeat and be unique to that site's URLs. But you also need to take into account sites where the authentication key or some other token is included in the middle of a URL and you need to avoid those. They will always be unique and of no use in this analysis.

Assuming you're building this for a known finite set of sites, this is possible to do. However, if you're say, at an ISPs gate, you'll get an insane number of unique sites. Any mapping/filtering to determine the correct unique parts of their paths will be an enormous task.

As an example of the 'keys' that appear in a URL, take a twitter status: `https://twitter.com/aneroidx/status/427684072920342528` ([link](https://twitter.com/aneroidx/status/427684072920342528)).
Here, the first part is the `domain`, then username (but not really 'path'), then '`status`' which is a part you know is a section to monitor, and then an unique 'tweet id' - which you wouldn't consider a section either. So you may need to determine these correct unique sections before you put them into a database, or put them in raw and run a separate program to create the proper entries for unique sections based on filters/rules like that above.

This is an much about hierarchical data as it is about filtering URL paths and sections correctly.

Comment: I was exactly looking to this kind of solution only...so would it be better to break the whole url into multiple tables associated with each other...(mapping) or i simply put this in one table with timestamp as primary key with multiple fields?

Comment: I would suggest breaking it into 2 tables so that you can feed in one table with raw URL & timestamp data (perhaps with a separate `domain` column). And in the 2nd table, you apply filtering rules to the URLs from the raw table and then insert records with counts/timestamps as required. For the hierarchy itself, using the 2 tables as the other answer is okay but getting the right data in it will take some additional effort as I've described above. You could put mapping rules into a table but you may find it easier to just put those into a separate readable/expandable file as part of your code

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. link?

Answer (score 1):

Add 'domain' column with index

```
create table URLS(
    id longint primary key,
    full_url varchar(255), 
    domain varchar(100)
    page_name varchar(100));
create index on URLS (domain);
create table parameters(
    id longint foreign key referencing URLS(id),
    param_name varchar(100),
    param_value varchar(100));

select count(a.full_url)
from URLS a, parameters b
where a.id=b.id
    and (b.param_name='user' and b.param_value='Jack');
```

Comment: It is just an example.Hierarchy can be much larger..in that case how to keep track of counting of individual parts as well as of different combination of components? let me give u a example..suppose xyz has come then x,x,y,y and xy...now i want to know how many time x and y together has come? moreover how many time x and y individually has come?

Comment: Take pen and paper and write full list of those parts and add needed fields.  Or simply use 'LIKE' in SELECT queries.

Comment: I see 3 global parts of URL. 1 - domain, 2 - name of page (index.html for example) and 3 - parameters, after "?"

Comment: can u provide me a more generalized solution if it is not for url...jst for xyz?

Comment: If you want more details from parameters, just create one more table **CREATE TABLE parameters(id LONGINT FOREIGN KEY, par_mane VARCHAR(255), par_value(255));**  And in main table add column *'id PRIMARY KEY'*

Comment: See my answer again, it's changed.

Comment: yeah..thanks a lot...now i am going in right direction